# Can DbVisualizer import table tata from a .sql file?

Tags: dbvisualizer

It seems that the only supported import data file format is `.csv`?

http://www.dbvis.com/doc/9.0/doc/ug/exportImport/exportImport.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .sql file with insert statements it can be executed in DbVisualizer as-is. Just load the script in the SQL editor and run the script to execute the insert statements.

Comment: If you have a big file, you can do it in that way

Comment: For really big sql files, use the @run <file.sql> command in the SQL Commander.

Comment: `@run` takes around 18 seconds per 1000 inserts to my remote server, even in a transaction. But it works.